# Can I call this a stub in JUnit testing?

Tags: junit, mockito

code -

```
@Test
public void testAddition() {
  Mockito.when(adder.add(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(22);  //is this stub
  Integer result = calculator.add(Integer.valueOf(10), Integer.valueOf(12));
  assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(22),result);
}
```

in the above code can i call below line as stub or test stub

```
  Mockito.when(adder.add(Mockito.anyInt(),Mockito.anyInt())).thenReturn(22);  //is this stub
```

If not, what is the technical term for this line, there should definitely be some.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call that line a stub or test stub.

As we know that a stub is a fake class that comes with preprogrammed return values.
A stub basically is injected into the class under test to give absolute control over what's being tested as input.
And this line does that actually.

Comment: cool.. welcome and thanks. +1  `this line does that actually`